# onClick on fires once in self executing function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery datepicker and need an self executing function for it to work properly so my JS looks like:

```
    $(function(){
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            // beforeShowDay: disableSpecificDays,
            inline: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            dayNamesMin: [ "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S" ],
        });

        $('#datepicker td').on('click', function() {
            console.log($(this).text());
        });
    });
```

My `onClick` event works, but it only fires once. And if I take it out of the function it doesn't fire at all.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: „self executing function“ there is no such thing and even not in your code. Why would you need an [immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)?

Comment: Is the <td> regenerated several times? If so, change to `$(document).on(selector,event, function)`

Comment: Have you tried using delegated events? (i.e. `$(document).on('click', '#datepicker td', function() {});`) See: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude i'll try that. Yes, i'm using jQuery datepicker so there's multiple `td` elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) event :

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
     onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        console.log(dateText);
         // you code here.. 
     }
 });
```

> Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this refers to the associated input field.

Or , You can simply re-attach your events to the ui-datepicker elements :

```
   var element = document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    cols = element.getElementsByTagName("td");

   attachEvents(); // call function on load

   function attachEvents() {
     for(var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
         cols[i].addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
            console.log(this);
            attachEvents();
          }, false);
     }
    }
```

Comment: If I do a console log on `this` within my `onSelect` method within the datepicker I get the `datepicker`. How can I target the actual `td` element I pressed? @Neeraj Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are attaching a click listener, the DOM element is not yet present. To overcome this problem, you need to use delegated event. Try using this code snippet:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        // beforeShowDay: disableSpecificDays,
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dayNamesMin: ["M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S"],
    });

    $('#datepicker').on('click', 'td', function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```